# Is there any other payment module other than Paypal?

Tags: android, paypal, e-commerce, payment

I am developing an e-commerce application in which I want to implement a payment module.

Looking for payment modules I found that there is a Paypal library available for Android.

I want to know if there are any other payment libraries?

Comment: In which country? There are many smaller payment services which are only used in one or two countries, but have a significant mindshare there...

Comment: for any country this can be work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using CreditCall... it has an XML API to do it. It also offers a Java library that automates the XML parsing. It allows you to pay using credit or debit card, as well as Paypal, all that through eKashu.

- [Documentation + a basic example](http://casidiablo.net/creditcallforandroid.zip)
- [CardEaseXML API Download](http://www.creditcall.com/cardease_xml.html)

Comment: can you provide any useful link for tutorial about implement CreditCall ?

Comment: Added Documentation and other useful link. What I like about this api is that it allows you to pay with paypal too...

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use Google Checkout, but I am not certain about this. Perhaps you may have an API for that. Just have a look.

[Google Checkout](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=sierra&continue=https://checkout.google.com/?gsessionid=zG5hmwDU5uOwSpoRjeELuA&upgrade=true&hl=en_US&nui=1&ltmpl=default)

[API Information - You can find examples at the bottom](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134461)

Comment: Yes, there's an API for it, and it supposedly integrates well. Another plus to it is that anyone who's bought an Android app already has an account, so no signup or CC input required. The API is relatively new, though, so not much feedback from people about its ease of use.